# Spark Sql is connecting to Derby DB for Hive meta store in place of my SQL and not able to find the Data Base

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using Cloudera VM. I have created SQLContext and trying to connect a hive Data base buit not able to. Similarly when I am creating a table from using spark sql , am not able to see in hive also.

I see the hive site xml has configuration for mysql db as metastore but spark is trying to connect derby db. Please let me know if I am missing some thing.

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
hiveContext=SQLContext(sc)
hiveContext.sql("use test ")
```

I can see it is connecting to DERBY DB.

```
16/06/19 18:51:32 INFO metastore.MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is DERBY
16/06/19 18:51:32 INFO metastore.ObjectStore: Initialized ObjectStore
16/06/19 18:51:33 WARN metastore.ObjectStore: Version information not found in metastore. hive.metastore.schema.verification is not enabled so recording the schema version 1.1.0


hive> show databases;
OK
default
test
Time taken: 0.571 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

Comment: I have copied the hive site xml in spark conf directory.cp hive-site.xml /etc/spark/conf/ and that's worked for me. Thanks.